# ASP.NET Core Angular 2 Webpack Hot Module Replacement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, webpack, asp.net-core

I've a blank ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 project where I'm trying to integrate Angular 2 from scratch with Webpack Module Bundler. I'm trying to use Hot Module Replacement (HMR) using ASP.NET Core SpaServices to avoid browser reload but I don't get any message on Browser's console saying HMR is connected! I have to manually run the webpack command to compile Typescript files and re-run the application. I'm using `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices": "1.0.0-*",` NuGet package. Also, I'm confronting the error in the browser's console as: `__webpack_hmr connetion refused`. Below is my `project.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.4.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.4.1",
        "@angular/core": "2.4.1",
        "@angular/forms": "2.4.1",
        "@angular/http": "2.4.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.1",
        "@angular/router": "3.4.1",
        "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.1",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
        "rxjs": "^5.0.3",
        "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "html-webpack-plugin": "2.26.0",
        "tsc": "1.20150623.0",
        "ts-loader": "2.0.0",
        "typescript": "2.1.5",
        "typings": "2.1.0",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.16.1",
        "webpack-node-externals": "1.5.4",
        "webpack-externals-plugin": "1.0.0",
        "aspnet-webpack": "1.0.27",
        "webpack": "2.2.1"
    }
}
```

The `Startup.cs` class's `Configure()` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole();
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
        {
            HotModuleReplacement = true
        });
    }

    app.UseMvc();

    DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
    options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
    options.DefaultFileNames.Add("Index.html");
    app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

and `webpack.config.js` file:

```
"use strict";

var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: { main: "./app/main.ts" },
    output: {
        filename: '/wwwroot/dist/bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/wwwroot/dist/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // Put webpack plugins here if needed, or leave it as an empty array if not
    ]
}
```

Also if you have any useful link or GitHub repo having Angular 2, Webpack and ASP.NET Core topics, please do share with me.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I downloaded a nice Visual Studio template pack from this blog post -> http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

The webpack.config.js file configures both a "main-client" and "main-server" boot file.  It is in boot-client.ts that I see the HMR being enabled within the browser:

```
import 'angular2-universal-polyfills/browser';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformUniversalDynamic } from 'angular2-universal';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import 'bootstrap';

// Enable either Hot Module Reloading or production mode
if (module['hot']) {
    module['hot'].accept();
    module['hot'].dispose(() => { platform.destroy(); });
} else {
    enableProdMode();
}
```

Hope that at least helps as a starting point!

Comment: This pack is installed. I tried it. But I'm writing a project from scratch with minimum components and configurations.

Comment: what about Angular 4 - `angular2-universal` is dead now

Comment: Wanted to leave this in case any ASP Core 2 people find this thread.  Since ASP Core 2 the angular template is now built into the toolkit.  You can setup a new project with the following CLI command `dotnet new angular`